# Php preg_match not working with content from Curl

Tags: php, curl, preg-match, special-characters

This my code

```
$urlArray = array();
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

When I use `print_r($result)` => result is:Tên Huyệt Mệnh Môn:

Thận khí là gốc của cơ thể. Huyệt nằm giữa 2 huyệt Thận Du, là cửa trọng yếu của sinh mệnh, vì vậy gọi là Mệnh Môn (Trung Y Cương Mục).

but I use `preg_match('|Tên Huyệt(.*)|', $result, $matches)` it return array empty.
I don't know why. Anyone tell me why, pls.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `u` modifier to correctly interpret UTF-8 strings.

```
preg_match('|Tên Huyệt(.*)|u', $result, $matches)
```

You can read a bit more about this [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Comment: it still not work with me. I remove <meta.., UTF-8> line  in my html  it show other symbol like as: Tên Huyá»‡t.......